# Facebook SDK error combined with Branch (Deep linking) - iOS

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, branch

I have a problem with the Facebook SDK if I use the Branch framework.

In my app I send a deeplink to new users this works perfectly but now my Facebook login is broken. I tried a couple of things already but it only works when I delete the application and install it again. Then I can log into Facebook but if I logout and try to login again it stops working.

Here my AppDelegate:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import FacebookCore
import HealthKit
import Branch


@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {


var window: UIWindow?
let healthkitManager = HealthkitManager()
var startedChallenge: StartedChallenge!

// latest
let sessionParams = Branch.getInstance().getLatestReferringParams()

// first
let installParams = Branch.getInstance().getFirstReferringParams()

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    // Navigation appearence
    let navigationBarAppearace = UINavigationBar.appearance()

    // Make navigation bar translucent
    navigationBarAppearace.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
    navigationBarAppearace.shadowImage = UIImage()
    navigationBarAppearace.isTranslucent = true

    // Make navigation bar text darkGray
    navigationBarAppearace.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.darkGray]
    navigationBarAppearace.tintColor = UIColor.white

    // White status bar
    UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent

    healthkitManager.authorize(forReadingQuantities: [.bodyMass, .height], forReadingCharacteristics: [.biologicalSex,.dateOfBirth])

    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)

    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)

    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "LaunchScreen", bundle: nil)
    let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SplashVC")
    self.window?.rootViewController = vc;
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    // ----------------------------------------------------------- Deep linking ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ //

    // listener (within AppDelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions)
    let branch: Branch = Branch.getInstance()

    // within AppDelegate application.didFinishLaunchingWithOptions
    branch.initSession(launchOptions: launchOptions, andRegisterDeepLinkHandler: { params , error in
        if let params = params, error == nil && params["~channel"] != nil {
            // params are the deep linked params associated with the link that the user clicked -> was re-directed to this app
            print("params: %@", params.description as Any)
            // load the view to show the viewcontroller
            let startedChallenge = StartedChallenge()
            startedChallenge.title = params[StartedChallenge.titleKey] as! String
            startedChallenge.category = params[StartedChallenge.categoryKey] as! String
            startedChallenge.days = Int(params[StartedChallenge.daysKey] as! String)!

            if let frequency = params[StartedChallenge.frequencyKey] as? String {
                startedChallenge.frequency = Int(frequency)!
            }

            let storyboard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Welcome", bundle: nil)
            let innerPageVC: InnerPageViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "InnerPageViewController") as! InnerPageViewController
            innerPageVC.startedChallenge = startedChallenge
            self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
            self.window?.rootViewController = innerPageVC
            self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

        } else {
            print("ADMIN: %@", params?.description as Any)
            var vcName = "Login"
            if UserManager.getToken() != nil {
                vcName = "Welcome"
                let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Welcome", bundle: nil)
                let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: vcName)
                self.window?.rootViewController = vc;
                self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
            } else {
                let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: vcName)
                self.window?.rootViewController = vc;
                self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

            }
        }
    })

    SDKApplicationDelegate.shared.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
    // always return true

    return true
}
```

I can't find the problem, if I disable Branch my Facebook login works.

Maybe someone can help me out :)

Answer (score 0):

Check your following callback method. Branch and Facebook SDK use same method. Is there any accidental change in call method.
Also, verify any change in URL schema which Facebook uses

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool {
        return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, open: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)
    }
```